# JDBCTemplate : either Update or Insert if ID doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Please see below the method which i used for updating a field in the table,
and now i have a condition if Id exists in the table then update the relative field otherwise insert a new record in the table.

1. Update if id exists
2. Insert a new record if id doesn't exist in table

Is there any way to do so via batch update which fulfils  both condition or any other way as i have to deal with hundreds of row altogether.

```
public void updateTable(List<TestClass> testList){

String UPDATE_ITEM_ARTICLENO = "UPDATE itemTable SET articleno=? WHERE itemId=?";

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(UPDATE_ITEM_ARTICLENO, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {         
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        TestClass article = testList.get(i);            
        ps.setString(1, article.getItemId());
        ps.setString(2, article.getArticleno());            
    }        
    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return testList.size();
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Where does the itemId come from?

Comment: What database are you using? You need to look at "merge" but its not supported by all databases. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)
You can then use the merge in the batch update

Comment: @DirkLachowski As i invoke the `updateTable` method & pass a list as parameter which holds the bean class objects. in the method, I get the object of bean  class and then get itemId from bean class object.

Comment: OK, and if a new item is created (so you have to insert and not to update), how is an id for the new item generated?

Comment: @DirkLachowski that's not my issue. please read once more.

Comment: @ShawnVader Thanks, seems i found the solution.i'll try it now

Comment: I think that is exactly your issue. If you don't want to do a read/write in a transaction (bad idea) then your next best option is to check if a new itemId has been generated (meaning you have to insert, not to update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a standard [Merge (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29%22) statement. But not all RDBMS's support it. Some of them have alternatives.